# Ejercicio de SQL con subconsultas/variables

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema y no se como resolverlo en este ejercicio.

Dice: ¿Qué personas fueron contratadas por alguna de las empresas que contrató a Stefanía Lopez?

Las tablas presentes son:

**Personas:**

```
direccion
apellido
nombre
dni
telefono
fecha_nacimiento
```

[image: Tabla personas]

**Empresas:**

```
nombre
cuit
e-mail
```

[image: Tabla empresas]

**Contratos:**

```
dni
cuit
nro_contrato
sueldo
```

[image: Tabla contratos]

El dni de los contratos corresponde a la persona contratada y el cuit a la empresa donde fue contratada.

Y la solución que estoy proponiendo, pero no me devuelve ningún registro es:

```
select p.`nombre`, p.`apellido`
from empresas e
inner join contratos cont
on e.`cuit` = cont.`cuit`
inner join personas p
on p.`dni` = cont.`dni`
where e.`cuit` in
(select cont.`cuit`
from contratos cont
inner join personas p
on p.`dni` = cont.`dni`
where p.`apellido` = 'Lopez' and p.`nombre` = 'Stefania');
```

Tengo claramente un error y no lo estoy viendo. Si alguien puede darme una mano se agradece.

Comment: Se me ocurre que puede deberse a 2 motivos. 1. Se escribe `Stefanía` (*con acento*). 2. Si `Stefanía` trabajó en mas de una empresa, deberías usar `where e.\`cuit\` IN (...`.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo he probado con eso y tampoco funciona. Pero esta bien lo del IN que me dijiste, trabajo en 2 empresas por lo tanto ese IN tiene que estar. Aun asi, sigue dandome 0 registros, cuando deberia darme 2.

Comment: ¿Podrías [editar tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/39411/edit) y agregar los datos que tienes en las tablas?

Comment: Listo @MarcosGallardo

Comment: Aparentemente tienes un problema de Cotejamiento (`Collation`). Puede que al importar los datos (o posterior a esto) el cotejamiento de la tabla o la columna `nombre` fue modificada. Intenta hacer la [comparación de `string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-literal.html) así: `p.\`nombre\` = _latin1 'Stefanía'` o `p.\`nombre\` = _utf8 'Stefanía'`

Comment: Aun nada. Cambie el nombre de la comparacion para ver si con otra persona funcionaba, pero sigue sucediendo lo mismo @MarcosGallardo

Comment: Listo, he probado con la comparacion usando unicamente el apellido y ahi si me arrojo todos los registros necesarios. No se como se areglará el problema del nombre pero ya puedo continuar al menos @MarcosGallardo

Comment: gracias @MarcosGallardo por tu ayuda!

Comment: ¿Que `collation` tiene la base de datos, la tabla o el campo?

Comment: La verdad que desconozco, estoy comenzando recién en esto de SQL @MarcosGallardo

Comment: ¿Que data te devuelve la subconsulta? También podría ser que los nombres se hayan almacenado con espacios en blanco. Prueba con un p.'nombre' like '%nombre%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que te sirva  :D

```
select p.`nombre`, p.`apellido`
from empresas e
inner join contratos cont  on e.`cuit` = cont.`cuit`
inner join personas p  on p.`dni` = cont.`dni`
inner join ( select cont.`cuit`
             from contratos cont
             where cont.`dni`` = '278090765' ) AS EMPSOFIA ON EMPSOFIA.`cuit`=cont.`cuit`;
```